# How to keep only unique rows but ignore a column?

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have this data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("apple", "apple", "apple", "orange", "orange"),
       ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
       is_fruit = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"))
```

and I want to keep only the unique rows, but ignore the `ID` column such that the output looks like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("apple", "orange"),
       ID = c(1, 4),
       is_fruit = c("yes", "yes"))

df2
#    name ID is_fruit
#1  apple  1      yes
#2 orange  4      yes
```

How can I do this, ideally with `dplyr`?

Comment: Base R: `df1[!duplicated(df1[-2]), ]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `distinct` function; By specifying the variables explicitly, you can retain unique rows just based on these columns; And also from `?distinct`:

> *If there are multiple rows for a given combination of inputs, only the first row will be preserved*

```
distinct(df1, name, is_fruit, .keep_all = T)
#    name ID is_fruit
#1  apple  1      yes
#2 orange  4      yes
```

Answer (score 4):

Base R

```
df1[!duplicated(df1[!names(df1) %in% c("ID")]),]
#    name ID is_fruit
#1  apple  1      yes
#4 orange  4      yes
```

Replace `c("ID")` with the names of the columns you want to ignore

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr's distinct with across

`df1 |> distinct(across(ID))`